# Why . sign used before number? in Dart/flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

What means sign . before number in Dart languge
exemple (.59):

```
double width = .59 * MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A decimal point, in other words it implies a leading zero.

e.g.

```
 print((.23.toStringAsFixed(3)));
```

output:

> 0.230

And;

```
var n = .34;
print (n.runtimeType);
```

will print `double`.

(though I don't see it specifically stated in the [double class documentation](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.17.5/dart-core/double-class.html), and not sure if that would be affected by locale/culture settings)